# How to get mouse co-ordinates in drop event Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I am only getting undefined:

```
 myele.bind('drop', function (e) {
            console.log("Dropped");
            if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
               //store
            }
            else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
               //store
            }
            console.log("XPOS: " + e.clientX + " YPOS: " + e.pageY);
            return false;
        });
```

Output:

Dropped
XPOS: undefined YPOS: undefined

**EDIT**

http://jsfiddle.net/fBT7X/2/

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue

Comment: @A.Wolff added the jsfiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery wraps the original drop event into a property called `originalEvent` so you have to access that to get the page/client properties

```
myele.bind('drop', function (e) {
   console.log("Dropped");
   if (e.originalEvent.pageX || e.originalEvent.pageY) {
      //store
   }
   else if (e.originalEvent.clientX || e.originalEvent.clientY) {
      //store
   }
   console.log("XPOS: " + e.originalEvent.clientX + " YPOS: " + e.originalEvent.pageY);
   return false;
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AZ4py/2/) Drag the green box to the red one

When you get an undefined on an object that you think has what you want, log the object to the console and look at it. In this case just log the event object and look through the properties

```
console.log(e);
   jQuery.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "drop", isDefaultPrevented: function, timeStamp: 1396687578486, jQuery110104013205280061811: true…}
   altKey: false
   bubbles: true
   cancelable: true
   ctrlKey: false
   currentTarget: div#e
   data: null
   delegateTarget: div#e
   eventPhase: 2
   handleObj: Object
   isDefaultPrevented: function returnFalse() {
   jQuery110104013205280061811: true
   metaKey: false
   originalEvent: MouseEvent <---
      altKey: false
      bubbles: true
      button: 0
      cancelBubble: false
      cancelable: true
      charCode: 0
      clientX: 24   <---
      clientY: 64   <---
      ...
   relatedTarget: null
   ...
```